# Make all html elements inline with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to display a button before and after a bootstrap datepicker inline all elements.

Does there exist a class/way in bootstrap 3.2 to easily make all elements inline within a certain container?

Throwing the span tag everywhere did not help just the opposite... now the datepicker comes first then the left arrow and then right arrow button.

How can I put all elements inline also without rewriting all former div tags as span tags?

```
<span><button class="btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></button></span>
<span class="row-fluid">
    <span class="col-md-4">
        <span class="input-group">
            <input
                    type="text"
                    class="form-control"
                    datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
                    ng-model="activeStep.now"
                    is-open="activeStep.open"
                    min-date="minDate"
                    max-date="'2015-06-22'"
                    datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                    date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"
                    ng-required="true"
                    close-text="Close"
                    />
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
              </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
<span><button class="btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></button></span>
```

Comment: AFAIK row-fluid is not part of bootstrap 3, row is already fluid. This is a form? Forms have different classes for inline, like form-inline on the form tag. Provide an image of what you intend with a Bootply/Bin/Fiddle, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Hope this helpful

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <span>
            <button class="btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <span class="row-fluid">
            <span class="col-md-12">
                <span class="input-group">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
                        ng-model="activeStep.now"
                        is-open="activeStep.open"
                        min-date="minDate"
                        max-date="'2015-06-22'"
                        datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                        date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"
                        ng-required="true"
                        close-text="Close" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)">
                            <i
                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <span>
            <button class="btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```